# Create a default Collection record for new user with Devise Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, devise

I hope you are well.

In my app, I have Posts and Collections

_ Collection 1

__ Post 1

__ Post 2

__ Post 3

I need to create a default collection for new user. So I need user_id, but I don't have it before user completes and sign up,

Should I check sign in count and create collection when user first signs in? or is there a better way?
Thank you

```
   def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        if resource.sign_in_count == 1
           Collection.create(title: 'default collection', user_id: current_user.id)
        end
    end
```

Comment: You could use a callback on your account model to create the needed records after creating the account

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_create

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need the 'after_create' one

Comment: YES! that's exactly what I been looking for! Thank you! after_create!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. it is working now with **after_action** : )

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  after_action :create_first_coll, only: [:create]

  def create_first_coll
    Collection.create(title: "First", user_id: @user.id)
  end
```

route

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    confirmations: 'users/confirmations',
    passwords: 'users/passwords',
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }, layout: 'devise'
```